# No such file or directory (Unable to find the directory)

Tags: python, listdir

I am writing code for calculating how many images are there in each folder. I have a folder that is dataset and it contains 12 sub-folders. Therefore, I want to show each amount of image data in every folder.

My code:

```
# get a list of image folders
folder_list = os.listdir('/content/dataset')

total_images = 0

# loop through each folder
for folder in folder_list:
    # set the path to a folder
    path = './content/dataset' + str(folder)
    # get a list of images in that folder
    images_list = os.listdir(path)
    # get the length of the list
    num_images = len(images_list)
    
    total_images = total_images + num_images
    # print the result
    print(str(folder) + ':' + ' ' + str(num_images))
    
print('\n')
# print the total number of images available
print('Total Images: ', total_images)
```

But I get the error below:

```
error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/datasetFat Hen'
```

Comment: Are you in linux or windows? Use "\\" within windows.

Comment: ```path = '/content/dataset/' + str(folder)``` you forgot the ```/``` after dataset. the error says it all

Comment: Windows, I am using google colab platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to add a trailing slash '/' to your string concatenation. Also, you need to remove the first dot from the path, as I understood from your comment.

```
path = '/content/dataset/' + str(folder)
```

But I would generally advice you to use [os.path.join](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/) to avoid such errors in the first place, instead of manually adding path strings.

```
for folder in folder_list:
    # set the path to a folder
    path = os.path.join('/content/dataset' + str(folder))
    #....
```

Comment: But the problem now appears in the following line 

images_list = os.listdir(path) @Alex Metsai

Comment: Furthermore, maybe you should be doing `path = '/content/dataset' + str(folder)` instead of `path = './content/dataset' + str(folder)` ? Without the first dot.

Comment: Sir, I have updated my answer and I solved it. But now I am facing the same problem that I posting with updated questions. The link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905583/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-for-showing-the-bar-g @Alex Metsai

Comment: I updated my answer then. I'll take a look at the other question as soon as I can. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pathlib` with a `dict` to store the results

```
from pathlib import Path

dirs = {}
base = Path('/content/dataset')
for folder in [pth for pth in base.glob('*') if pth.is_dir()]:
    dirs[folder.as_posix()] = len([subpth for subpth in folder.rglob('*') if subpth.is_file()])

for k, v in dirs.items():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
    
print()
print(f'Total Images: {sum(dirs.values())}')
```

Comment: I have faced an error that is: `name 'pth' is not defined` ..
afterwords, I rewrite `pth as path` then there is another error appears `'str' object has no attribute `rglob` @Eric Truett