# FileNotFoundError: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' for showing the bar graph according to the several classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, listdir

I am going to demonstrate the Bar graph where it will show the statistical result of several classes of images presented in each sub-folder. I have written the code but it appears error

My code:

```
#Class Name
image_folder = ['AB','','AC','AA','BB', 'BA', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'DD','EE' ]
nimgs = {}
for i in image_folder:
    nimages = len(os.listdir('/content/dataset/'+i+'/'))
    nimgs[i]=nimages
plt.figure(figsize=(34, 12))
plt.bar(range(len(nimgs)), list(nimgs.values()), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(nimgs)), list(nimgs.keys()))
plt.title('Distribution of different classes of Dataset')
plt.show()


Error in line : nimages = len(os.listdir('/content/dataset/'+i+'/'))
```

Error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/dataset/AB/'`

Comment: you meant  `content/nonsegmentedv2//content/dataset//AB/`?

Comment: Are you sure that the error occurs in this line? I can't seem to understand how the `nonsegmentedv2` folder was accessed.

Comment: `nimgs[i]=nimages` this is wrong, you should use `enumerate` for this.

Comment: E.g. `for i, path in enumerate(image_folder)`

Comment: Sir, I do not understand the point. Could You please write it elaborately @Alex Metsai

Comment: I updated the error @AlexMetsai

Answer (score 1):

The empty str in image_folder is causing the error.
When the iterator reaches the empty string, you are effectively trying to define a folder as an image!

Comment: Could you please precise the answer?@Derek?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Class Name
image_folder = ['AB','','AC','AA','BB', 'BA', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'DD','EE' ]
nimgs = {}
for i in image_folder:
    nimages = len(os.listdir('/content/dataset/'+i+'/'))
    nimgs[i]=nimages
plt.figure(figsize=(34, 12))
plt.bar(range(len(nimgs)), list(nimgs.values()), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(nimgs)), list(nimgs.keys()))
plt.title('Distribution of different classes of Dataset')
plt.show()
```

Solution: `['AA','AB','AC','BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'DD','EE' ]`
The problem was about the respective serial of the class name